# How to wait for a response in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

So I am talking to something externally and I have just sent it a message, I will expect an almost immediate response but I will wait for a second in case there is a delay. A separate thread is monitoring for an input and will set a flag "newdataflag" when it has received this data. All I am trying to do below is wait in a while loop until this flag is set or 1 second elapses.

```
 private bool WaitrxData()
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer waitrxtimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        waitrxtimer.Tick += waitrxtimer_Tick;
        waitrxtimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        waitrxtimer.IsEnabled = true;
        waitrxtimer.Start();
        statusText.Text = "Waiting For Response";
        //wait for new data
        while (!newdataflag)
        { 
            if (waitrxcounter > 100)
            {
                statusText.Text = "No Response";
                break;
            }
        }
        waitrxtimer.Stop();
        if (waitrxcounter > 100)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            newdataflag = false;
            return true;
        }

    }

    private void waitrxtimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        waitrxcounter++;
    }
```

This code works if the response is so immediate the while loop is skipped but if not, the code will not execute the timer and just get stuck in the while loop and crash. I think this is because the timer is not creating a new thread to tick like I thought it would?

Maybe I am doing the wrong thing?

Cheers

Comment: Use `ManualResetEventSlim` instead of loops for waiting for an event. This will block the thread, however. But you block the thread in your example either.

Comment: Ideally you can make and async call.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/walkthrough-accessing-the-web-by-using-async-and-await

Comment: I just want to add why your timer does not get the Tick event when you enter the while loop - because the DispatcherTimer will invoke the tick handler once the same thread cycling in the while loop polls its message queue and finds a WM_TIMER message. This all is done under the hood in the Dispatcher implementation via WndProc hooking, but in short - while your loop keeps the main thread busy, no messages are being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of busy waiting in a loop you could `await Task.Delay()` with a CancellationToken:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
...

private async Task<bool> Wait()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// cancel Wait() from another method
cts.Cancel();
```

Comment: I get an error: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Delay'

Comment: It's there since .Net 4.5.

Comment: Im using visual studio professional 2012 version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5. .NET Version 4.7.02558.

Does this crash and get caught by the catch if the cancel token is used? I would rather a more robust solution?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "crash".

Comment: Sorry I was targetting the wrong framework. I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>' to 'bool'" on all my function calls now

Comment: You have to call `bool result = await Wait()` because it's async. Make yourself familiar with async/await.